# Getting elements from a sub-list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a .csv file which contains the following 4 lines of elements:

```
dev1, NX-OS, 10.0.0.1, admin, admin
dev2, NX-OS, 10.0.0.2, admin, admin
dev3, NX-OS, 10.0.0.3, admin, admin
dev4, NX-OS, 10.0.0.4, admin, admin
```

I am trying to extract any of the elements. In order to do this, I've the following:

```
import csv
dev_list=[]
infile=open('dev_in.csv','r')
csv_in=csv.reader(infile)

for dev in csv_in:
    dev_list.append(dev)
```

The result out of `dev_list` is the following list of lists:

```
[
    ['dev1, NX-OS, 10.0.0.1, admin, admin'],
    ['dev2, NX-OS, 10.0.0.2, admin, admin'],
    ['dev3, NX-OS, 10.0.0.3, admin, admin'],
    ['dev4, NX-OS, 10.0.0.4, admin, admin']
]
```

In order to extract the first element of the first list, I coded:

```
element=dev_list[0]
print(element[0])
```

However, I'm getting the complete first list as a result:

```
dev1, NX-OS, 10.0.0.1, admin, admin
```

Maybe I should split it with the 'split' function but I think that would extend the code unnecessarily. What I need to extract the first elements of each sub-list. However, I may need later to extract other elements.

Is there another way? Is there also a better way to write this code, maybe with list comprehension Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless `csv` had a way to handle delimiters, this is exactly the time to use `split`. It would only add like one line.

Comment: Why not use Pandas for reading in csv files?

Comment: You don't need to `split()` at all,  `csv.reader()` do that already. You need to change your code to be something like `devs = list(csv.reader(open('dev_in.csv'), skipinitialspace=True))`. After that `devs` will be a list of lists so, in order to have the dev names, for example,  you do `for dev in devs: print(dev[0])`.

Comment: The resulting list you posted on your question is not what you get from the code you posted.

Comment: @accdias I checked the code again, and that's what I get. Do you get something different?

Comment: @Alex, yep. Check the output on the proof of concept I posted on my answer.

Comment: Can anyone else try my answer and post the results? Author of OP is still having problems. I tried it on PyCharm 2019.3.1 and Python 3.7/3.8 on Windows, Python 3.7/3.8 on [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin/com)/Windows, Python 3.7 on MacOS and Linux, and couldn't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing my comment, here is what you need to do (with Python 3 in mind):

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path

dev_in = Path('dev_in.csv')

devs = list(csv.reader(dev_in.open(), skipinitialspace=True))

for dev in devs:
    # print dev names
    print(dev[0])
```

Code above will give the following lines as output:

```
dev1
dev2
dev3
dev4
```

Here is a proof of concept:

```py
Python 3.7.5 (default, Dec 15 2019, 17:54:26) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import csv
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> dev_in = Path('dev_in.csv')
>>> 
>>> devs = list(csv.reader(dev_in.open(), skipinitialspace=True))
>>> devs
[['dev1', 'NX-OS', '10.0.0.1', 'admin', 'admin'], ['dev2', 'NX-OS', '10.0.0.2', 'admin', 'admin'], ['dev3', 'NX-OS', '10.0.0.3', 'admin', 'admin'], ['dev4', 'NX-OS', '10.0.0.4', 'admin', 'admin']]
>>> dev=devs[0]
>>> dev
['dev1', 'NX-OS', '10.0.0.1', 'admin', 'admin']
>>> dev[0]
'dev1'
>>>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I'm getting the same error. The list I get out of your `devs` is the following: `[['dev01, NX-OS, 10.0.0.1, admin, admin'], ['dev02, NX-OS, 10.0.0.2, admin, admin'], ['dev03, NX-OS, 10.0.0.3, admin, admin'], ['dev04, NX-OS, 10.0.0.4, admin, admin']]`. I can see that each element of my list doesn't have the quotation marks as yours, what allows you to choose the desired element.This is the very same list I get from my code out of the `dev_list`.

Comment: Maybe it is something with your `csv` module. Here I'm using `csv.__version__` `1.0`.

Comment: I'm also using the 1.0 version.

Comment: So definitely there's something broken on your Python installation. :-(

Comment: I'm not quite sure of that. I'm running Python Python 3.8.1 (latest version) on Pycharm for Windows at the moment. I tried also with the regular Python Shell. I did the same on another computer and I'm always getting the same error. I also tried with Python 3.7 and the result persists :(

Comment: I'm on Linux and tried the same code on an Windows machine but on Python from [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). Also did some test on a MacOS machine and got the result expected. I will try PyCharm to see if I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello @accdias, did you try with PyCharm?